# Не срабатывают исключения

Tags: javascript

Только начал учиться (1 неделя) и столкнулся с проблемой.
Дано: пишу программу "Угадай число" со своими доработками. Именно эта проблема в части присвоения имени.

```
let chooseName;
            if (players > 1) { //возможность ввести имена игроков в режиме нескольких игроков
                chooseName = prompt ('Хотите ввести имена игроков? \nНапишите "да", если хотите.')
            } else { //возможность для одного игрока
                chooseName = prompt ('Хотите ввести имя игрока? \nНапишите "да", если хотите.'); 
            }
            if (chooseName == 'да' || chooseName == 'ДА' || chooseName == 'Да') {   //условие ввода имен игроков
                for (var i = 0; i < players; i++) { //цикл на ввод имени игроков
                playersName[i] = prompt ('Введите имя ' + (i + 1) + ' игрока.'); //ввод имени
                if (playersName[i] == undefined || playersName[i] == "" || playersName[i] == null) { //условие для проверки
                    let conf = prompt ('Вы уверены, что не хотите давать имя игроку №' + (i + 1) + '? \nЕсли да, то оставьте поле пустым, если нет, то введите имя игрока.'); //условие на пустое поле
                    if (conf !== "" || conf !== undefined || conf !== null) { //последний шанс ввести имя
                        playersName[i] = conf;
                    } else { //присвоение номера вместо имени
                        playersName[i] = ('Игрок №' + (i + 1));
                    }
                }
                } //конец цикла на ввод имени игроков
            } else { //отказ от введения имени
                for (var i = 0; i < players; i++) { //цикл на присвоение порядковых номеров игрокам
                    playersName[i] = ('Игрок №' + (i + 1));
                } //конец цикла на присвоение номеров
            } //конец цикла на присвоение имен
```

Так вот, суть проблемы:

1. первая проверка на пустую строку проходит успешно, но когда через переменную "conf" я запрашиваю ещё раз, то независимо от значения, "" или null, меня пропускает переименовать переменную. Пробовал всё, что в голову пришло: изначально стояло "!=", потом сменил на "!==", также пытался заменить "или" на "и" - не помогло. Пробовал деактивировать часть условия через "/* */" - не пускает только, когда имеется только "", в остальных случаях, даже когда стоит только "null", по esc все равно позволяет переименовать переменную.
   Примечание: если поставить условие так 'if (conf != "") {', то всё работает как должно. Но при добавлении других условий - перестает. А при "пропуске" через esc playersName принимает значение null :/

Вторая проблема решена ответом

2. как вы могли заметить, это всё зациклено в "for" - это сделано для нескольких игроков(завязано на массиве и сколько игроков играют, столько раз он спрашивает имя). Так вот условие на проверку, которое некорректно работает, срабатывает только при первом цикле, на втором-третьем-пятом эта проверка просто пропускается(смотрел в хроме пошагово).

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (playersName == undefined || ...
```

а где ключ у переменной playersName??
вот может так надо?)

```
if (playersName[i] == undefined || ...
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Спасибо, теперь спрашивает каждый цикл, но проблема с "conf" так и не решилась. Почему-то, при пустом значении "conf", "playersName" принимает значение "conf", хотя по условию должен брать значение "Игрок № (i +1)"

Comment: пойдите не от обратного, а как у вас в примере проверки выше. то есть не проверяйте если НЕ равно, проверяйте если равно. то есть измените проверку так: if (conf == "" || conf == undefined || conf == null) { playersName[i] = ('Игрок №' + (i + 1)); } else  playersName[i] = conf;